# Converting Kotlin to Java using kotlin byte code gives java code with bugs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm using Android Studio and trying to convert Kotlin code to Java using Kotlin byte code. After de-compile, I get complex Java code with some bugs. Is there any alternate method or what should I do?

Comment: Kotlin generates Java code under the hood, all its features are implemented by generating all that complex code, so you don't have to worry about it yourself. It's not meant to be used as written Java code, because like you've noticed, it's pretty complex. Shouldn't be any bugs though (if the Kotlin is written properly)

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? What is your goal? If you have the code in Kotlin why transform it to Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no alternatives, and the only way is to solve bugs by yourself.
That is mentioned in Kotlin documentation.

Comment: Could you please specify where it is specified in the documentation?